# default() method in Python

Tags: python, default, encoder

I am making an Encoder for converting python objects to json and when researching I see a lot of solutions that include a `default` method.  I'm not an expert in Python, but definitely not a novice either, and I'm wondering if I somehow missed that there is a `default` method that gets run automatically when a class is called.  Or, is this just because I have inherited from the `JSONEcoder` class (which has a default method, and I am now just overriding)?  Can someone clarify?  And if so, is it basically the same as the

```
__init__()
```

method?

By the way, my encoder looks like this if you need more of a visual:

```
class ComplexEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, my_custom_object):
            return str(obj)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`JSONEncoder` has a `default` method which gets called if it doesn't know how to coerce a particular object into valid JSON.  The default implementation just raises `TypeError` (because it doesn't know how to coerce the type).  However, when *you* override the default method, you have a chance to return an object that the encoder *does* know how to handle.  If *you* don't know how to handle the type that is input (e.g. it isn't an instance of `my_custom_type`), then you should either `raise TypeError` yourself, or call the `default` method on `JSONencoder` so that it can raise the error.

Frequently, you'll see `super` used here for cooperative inheritance:

```
class ComplexEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, my_custom_object):
            return str(obj)
        return super(ComplexEncoder, self).default(obj)
```

If *all* the encoder classes you build are of this form, you can mix them together:

```
class MySuperEncoder(ComplexEncoder, WidgetEncoder, FooEncoder):
    pass
```

Now `ComplexEncoder` will handle the things it knows about (e.g. `my_custom_object`), `WidgetEncoder` will encode the things that it knows how to handle (probably `Widget` instances), and so forth.

Answer (score 2):

Runnning `dir(JSONEncoder)` gives us:

```
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__doc__',
 '__format__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__module__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 'default',  # We found our method, let's see what it does
 'encode',
 'item_separator',
 'iterencode',
 'key_separator']
```

Running `help(JSONEncoder.default)` gives us:

```
default(self, o) unbound json.encoder.JSONEncoder method
    Implement this method in a subclass such that it returns
    a serializable object for ``o``, or calls the base implementation
    (to raise a ``TypeError``).

    For example, to support arbitrary iterators, you could
    implement default like this::

        def default(self, o):
            try:
                iterable = iter(o)
            except TypeError:
                pass
            else:
                return list(iterable)
            # Let the base class default method raise the TypeError
            return JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
```

So it would seem it's designed this way for you to write your own should you subclass this object.

Answer (score 1):

I think this method is defined in `json.JSONEncoder` as described [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html). `default(o)` should return a serializable version of the given object or pass it to its superclass.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I kind of started thinking, too.  Just wasn't sure about if default() was some sort of `magic method` that I didn't know about.  Thanks!